# How to convert char pointer to float in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I've looked around everywhere and tried pretty much everything suggested and can't get anything to work.

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
      float a;
      char *nums[3];
      char str[5];
      printf("Please enter a,b,c:");
      scanf("%s",str);
      int i=0;
      char *p;
      p = strtok (str,",");
      while (p != NULL)
        {
          nums[i++] = p;
          p = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
      a=atof(nums[0]);
      printf("%s\n",nums[0]);
      printf("%f\n",a);
      return 0;
}
```

the math.h is for something later on after I figure this out. So if I entered "1,2,3" into this program, my print statements would show me "1" and then "0.000", this is obviously just there for me to test things out but why the does my value just disappear after trying to convert to a float? I need that value of 1 to do math with later in my program but I can't get that char pointer value no matter what I try, I can only seem to print it,  but it screws up as soon as I try to convert it into a type I can use.

Comment: "1,2,3" is 5 characters, so you've got an overflow of your `str` var before you even start...

Comment: And `nums` is an array of two pointers, into which you put three pointers. And I see no declaration for `a`.

Comment: as John3136 said, you need to write char str[5]. but also, you never really defined variable a, used on here: printf("%f\n",a);

Comment: sorry about the no declaration I had a bit of code before that was mostly useless, I do have a float a declaration in the beginning, also I know 1,2,3 is 5 characters but don't arrays start at 0? so a size 4 should fit 5

Comment: A size of 4 has indexes 0,1,2,3. And in fact the size needs to be 6, since `scanf` puts a NUL character after the string that you enter. Ideally you should just make the size a really big number (like 256), so that the user has to actually try hard to overflow your buffer. Or you can limit the number of characters written into the buffer with `scanf("%5s",str)`. That would limit the number of characters to 5 plus the NUL terminator, for a total of 6.

Comment: one thing is the index another is the size. Index starts at 0 but the size also counts index 0 as one.

Comment: Ok, but that's not where I'm getting my problems from, what I want to figure out is why does my value disappear once I convert my num[0] into a float? because regardless of my array size num[0] is still grabbing the very first number entered. I'll fix it in my example though, but that's not where the problem is coming from, it's from the last 4 lines of my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

You `nums` and `str` arrays are too short.  `nums` should have a size of at least 3, and `str` should be at least 6 ("1,2,3" plus null byte), probably more for larger numbers.

So change those to:

```
  char *nums[3];
  char str[20];
```

Second, you don't `#include <stdlib.h>`, which contains the declaration of `atof`.  Without a declaration, it is assumed to return an `int`.

Fix the array sizes, and `#include <stdlib.h>`, and it should work.